# a complex merge in R to flag unmatched observations?

Tags: r, function, merge, append, apply

I'm trying to join two datasets together. Call them x and y. I believe that the ID variables in y are a subset of the ID variables in x. But not in the pure sense because I know that x contains more IDs than y but I don't know the mapping. That is, some (but not all) of the IDs in x and y can be matched 1:1.

My ultimate goal is to figure out where this 1:1 mapping fails and flag these observations. I thought merge would be the way to go but maybe not. An example is below:

```
id <- c(1:10, 1:100)

X1 <- rnorm(110, mean = 0, sd = 1)
year <- c("2004","2005","2006","2001","2002") 
year <- rep(year, 22)

month = c("Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec","Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr")
month <- rep(month, 11)

#dataset X
x <- cbind(id, X1, month, year)

#dataset Y
id2 <- c(1:10, 200)
Y1 <- rnorm(11, mean = 0 , sd = 1)
y <- cbind(id2,Y1)

#merge on the IDs; but we get an error because when id2 == 200 in y we don't 
#have a match in x 
result <- merge(x, y, by.x="id", by.y = "id2", all =TRUE)
```

The merge threw an error because id2 == 200 had no match in the x dataset. Unfortunately, I lost the ID and all the information as well! (it should equal 200 in row 111):

```
tail(result) 
      id                   X1 month year         Y1
106   95  -0.0748386054887876   Nov 2002         NA
107   96    0.196765325477989   Dec 2004         NA
108   97    0.527922135906927   Jan 2005         NA
109   98    0.197927230533413   Feb 2006         NA
110   99 -0.00720474886698309   Mar 2001         NA
111 <NA>                 <NA>  <NA> <NA> -0.9664941
```

What's more, I get duplicate observations on the ID variable in the merged file. The id2 == 1 observation only existed once but it just copied it twice (e.g. Y1 takes on the value 1.55 twice).

```
head(result)
   id                 X1 month year       Y1
1   1  -0.67371266313441   Jul 2004 1.553220
2   1 -0.318666983469993   Jul 2004 1.553220
3  10 -0.608192898092431   Apr 2002 1.234325
4  10  -0.72299929212347   Apr 2002 1.234325
5 100 -0.842111221826554   Apr 2002       NA
6  11  -0.16316681842082   Jul 2004       NA
```

This merge has made things more complicated than I intended. I was hoping I could examine every observation in x and figure out where the id matched id2 in y and flag the ones that didn't. So I would get a new vector, call it flag, that takes on a value 1 if x$id had a match in y$id2 and zero otherwise. This way, I could know where the 1:1 mapping failed. I could potentially get some traction on this by re-coding the NAs, but what about the error that gets thrown when id2 == 200? It just discards the information.

I have tried appending by rows with no luck and it looks like I should give up merge as well, perhaps it's better to wring a loop or function to do something along these lines:

for every observation in x

id2 = which(id2) corresponds to id-month-year

flag = 1 if length of above is == 1, 0 otherwise

etc.

Hopefully this all makes sense. I'd be very grateful for any help or guidance.

Comment: `cbind` creates matrices, not data frames. Your calls to create `x` and `y` should be `x <- data.frame(id,X1,month,year)` and `y <- data.frame(id2,Y1)`.

Comment: You are getting two observations for `y$id2 == 1` because there are two rows in `x` where `x$id == 1`. If the merge sees multiple observations that match the join criteria, it will create a row for each possible combination. This is by design and is very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for which things in `x$id` are in `y$id2`, then you can use

```
x$id %in% y$id2
```

to get a logical vector returning matches. It does not guarantee a 1-to-1 correspondence, however; just a 1-to-many. You can then add this vector to your data frame

```
x$match.y <- x$id %in% y$id2
```

to see what rows of `x` have a corresponding ID in `y`.

To see which observations are 1-to-1, you could do something like

```
y$id2[duplicated(y$id2)] #vector of duplicate elements in y$id2
(x$id %in% y$id2) & !(x$id %in% y$id2[duplicated(y$id2)])
```

to filter out elements that appear more than once in `y$id2`. You can also add this to `x`:

```
x$match.y.unique <- (x$id %in% y$id2) & !(x$id %in% y$id2[duplicated(y$id2)])
```

The same procedure can be done for `y` to determine what rows of `y` match in `x`, and which ones match uniquely.

Comment: `duplicated` returns a boolean vector. You want `y$id2[duplicated(y$id2)]`

Comment: Right on! I realized my mistake and spent a couple minutes at the edit screen trying to remember the right syntax. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like this option doesn't work well when y$id2 == 200 and does not have a match in x$id. It should be false but comes up true: 

`test <- (x$id %in% y$id2) & !(x$id %in% y$id2[duplicated(y$id2)])`  

`test <- data.frame(x,y,test)`    

`test[1:20,]# first 20 rows`  

In row 11, we have id2 corresponding to id which is not a 1:1 and should be 'FALSE' but comes up 'TRUE'. Then all the subsequent lines are messed up. So we have 2 == 1 = TRUE in row 12, etc.

Comment: The vector I propose in the solution is a logical vector telling which elements of `x$id` can be matched uniquely and in a 1-to-1 manner with an element of `y$id2`. Consider `x$one.to.one <- (x$id %in% y$id2) & !(x$id %in% y$id2[duplicated(y$id2)])` and looking at `x` afterwards.

Comment: Also, I do not think `data.frame(x,y,test)` does what you think. The `data.frame` command will just mash its arguments together, not merging by `id`. Additionally, because `y` in this instance has fewer rows than `x`, it gets [recycled to fill up the space](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#The-recycling-rule) and so will be repeated 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your merge failed was that you gave it two different structures (one a numeric matrix and the other a character matrix) for x and y. Using `cbind` when `data.frame` should be chosen is a common strategy for failure.

```
> str(x)
 chr [1:110, 1:4] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "10" "1" "2" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "id" "X1" "month" "year"
> str(y)
 num [1:11, 1:2] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "id2" "Y1"
```

If you used the `data.frame` function (since dataframes are what `merge` is supposed to be working with) it would have succeeded:

```
> x <- data.frame(id, X1, month, year); y <- data.frame(id2,Y1)
> str( result <- merge(x, y, by.x="id", by.y = "id2", all =TRUE) )
'data.frame':   111 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ id   : num  1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 ...
 $ X1   : num  1.5063 2.5035 0.7889 -0.4907 -0.0446 ...
 $ month: Factor w/ 10 levels "Apr","Aug","Dec",..: 6 6 2 2 10 10 9 9 8 8 ...
 $ year : Factor w/ 5 levels "2001","2002",..: 3 3 4 4 5 5 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ Y1   : num  1.449 1.449 -0.134 -0.134 -0.828 ...

> tail( result <- merge(x, y, by.x="id", by.y = "id2", all =TRUE) )
     id         X1 month year        Y1
106  96 -0.3869157   Dec 2004        NA
107  97  0.6373009   Jan 2005        NA
108  98 -0.7735626   Feb 2006        NA
109  99 -1.3537915   Mar 2001        NA
110 100  0.2626190   Apr 2002        NA
111 200         NA  <NA> <NA> -1.509818
```

If you have duplicates in your 'x' argument, then you *should* get duplicates in the result. It's then your responsibility to use `!duplicated` in whatever manner you deem appropriate (either before or after the merge), but you cannot expect `merge` to be making decisions like that for you.